# How to add new line in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm using rhel7 and trying to print my output from shadow for example to be like this :

```
test1 !!
test2 !!
test3 *
```

I am running this command:

```
i=`cat /home/mydir/shadow1 |awk -F ':' '{print $1,$2}' `
```

When I do `echo $i`, it will print the output in 1 line:

```
test !! test2 !! test3 *
```

Can anyone advice how should I modify my `'{print $1,$2}'` so that it will print a new line?

Comment: You've not double quoted your variable when you use it, so the shell has re-interpreted the result - and this includes replacing a white space (and newlines) with single spaces

Comment: You may also want to look at `passwd --status`

Comment: Finally, don't use backticks for command evaluation. Use the relatively modern `$( command )` syntax instead

Comment: Do you need your shell variable `i` for anything else? If not, there's no point in having it at all. Just `awk ... shadow1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is clear. This problem can be approached in different ways. Not sure what the intention is but you can use for example the following:

```
while IFS=: read -r user stat _; do echo "$user" "$stat"; done < /etc/shadow
```

If you want to store the whole output of awk you could use something like this:

```
 var=$(awk -F: '{print $1,$2}' /etc/shadow)
```

You'd then just need to `echo "$var"` to print the results.

Comment: Thank you. I'm able to get my output now!

Comment: I'm adding this "while IFS= read -r line" to my array in the scripting, all good now! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your awk print-statement is all fine.

Use quotes for echo:

```
echo "$i"
```

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *echo $i*, try using:

```
echo -e "$i\n"
```

This adds a line break at the end of the line.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its working as well! Thank you!